# is this the correct declarative, data-dojo-type syntax to require a package?

Tags: dojo, amd

I have a package, defined in `dojoConfig` like this:

```
packages: [ 
    { name: 'Widget', location: '/widgets/Widget' } 
]
```

The `/widgets/Widget/main.js` file defines my main module. With this config, in Javascript i can `require` the module `Widget/main` directly by its package name like this:

```
require(["Widget"], function(Widget){
    var widget = new Widget();
    // all is well
});
```

But doing the same using declarative syntax throws a **Unable to resolve constructor for: 'Widget'** error:

```
<div data-dojo-type="Widget"></div>
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to see how widget is created, but the complaint is that you have no constructor. 
a constructor is required for a widget.  If you extend WidgetBase its done for you.

check the doc:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/writingWidgets.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the

```
require(["Widget"], function(Widget){});
```

part in a script tag in the HTML document you are using

```
<div data-dojo-type="Widget"></div>
```

It should look like something:

```
<script> require(["Widget"], function(Widget){}); </script>
```

You have to require the module/widget before you can call it in an HTML page the same way you need to do it in a script tag.

Comment: thanks, but i already tried that.. and i just tried it again.. `<script> require(["Widget"], function(Widget){ console.log(Widget); }); </script>` prints the Widget as expected, but the `<div data-dojo-type="Widget"></div>` fails with `Unable to resolve constructor`.

Comment: Do you have a constructor method inside your widget?